# when reading logs, JSON changes from double quotes to single quotes

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, logging, streaming

With the apache logs (below) I'm able to parse out a JSON:

```
[2014.02.14_21.24.22.543] other info I don't care about json: {
  "petstore": "store_number_8",
  "dogs":{
    "terrier":{
      "total":2
    }
  },
  "cat":{
    "siamese":{
      "total":5
    }
  }
}
```

1) Is this valid JSON? 2) Why would the double quotes be turning into single quotes?

After I read it in, parse out the JSON, and display it I get the following:

```
{
  'petstore': 'store_number_8',
  'dogs':{
    'terrier':{
      'total':2
    }
  },
  'cat':{
    'siamese':{
      'total':5
    }
  }
}
```

Btw, I'm using Node.js' `fs.createStream` to read in the logs, then simply doing a console out (so far I'm not doing any sanitization and eventually I will be writing it to a file).

```
fs.creatReadStream(logs).pipe(split()).on(data, function(line){
  if(line.match(/json\:/)){
    shouldThisBeValidJSON = JSON.parse(line.slice(line.indexOf('{'), line.length));
    console.log(shouldThisBeValidJSON);
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`console.log` doesn't return JSON. It returns human-readable representation of this object.

So no, it's not JSON, it's something closer to JSON5.

If you want JSON to be displayed, you have to pass a string to console.log, i.e. `console.log(JSON.stringify(shouldThisBeValidJSON))`